# rake: Define length of string and integer cols

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I searched for this, but didnt find anything, so here's my problem:

How can I set the length of strings and integers in a rake create table statement?

Example MySQL:

```
create table table (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  string1 varchar(30) not null,
  string2 varchar(50) not null,
  int tinyint(3) not null default '0'
)
```

I don't want to set all these columns to varchar(255) or a large integer when I only need to store a shorter amount of characters.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html doesn't write anything about this :/

How should I attempt this?

Comment: the doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html says about it see here: `limit Sets the maximum size of the string/text/binary/integer fields.` just find and read.

Comment: A "thank you" to you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a table, migrations are the way to go. The doc does a good job showing [how to set them up](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration) & [configure them](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#column-modifiers). This can be a bit overwhelming, so here's the important part for you:

### 1 - Create a migration from your terminal

run `rails g migration create_foo_model`, you will find the new file in */db/migrations*

### 2 - Set up your model as desired

For your case I added the options `limit` & `default`.

```
class CreateFooModelMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :foo do |t|
    t.string :string1, :limit => 30
    t.string :string2, :limit => 50
    t.integer :int1, :limit => 3, :default => 0
  end
end
```

Then you should run `rake db:migrate`, which will run this code and therefor setup your table.